# Oracle : SQL with REGEXP and RTRIM for Oracle 8i

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this RTRIM and REGEXP function in Oracle SQL query which is working fine in Oracle 10g
but is not working in Oracle 8i. How can I convert the following statement to something working in both Oracle 8i and 10g and still having the same result.

```
RTRIM(regexp_substr(table.column1, '([^/]+\.)'), '.')
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: 8i does not have regular expressions. I don't see a sensible way to simulate them there. And besides: 8i has been de-supported for a very long time. You should really, really upgrade (and 10g isn't going to be supported for long either)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer :

```
    SUBSTR(table.column1, INSTR(table.column1, '/', -1) + 1,
    INSTR(table.column1, '.') - INSTR(table.column1, '/', -1) - 1)
```

^_^